# "Сидіти на останньому ряді" чи "Сидіти в останньому ряду"?

Tags: прийменники

Ґуґл знаходить обидва варіанти, чи обидва є нормативними?

Декілька прикладів з пошуку:

З перекладу "Долина Совісті" Дяченків (видавництво "Зелений Пес"):

> Тож Влад **сидів на останньому ряді** біля стіни, Ганна - на першому біля вікна.

"Діва Млинища",

> за ними йшов назирцем Левко — він теж дивився в клубі те кіно, як зазвичай, **в останньому ряду**.

Answer (score 3):

Тут можуть виникнути дві проблеми:

- **Закінчення іменника *ряд*.** *Ряд* - іменник чоловічого роду другої відміни твердої групи, в місцевому відмінку однини такі іменники [мають](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm) закінчення `-у`. Хоча цей [форум](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t2659.html) все ж каже (а [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/rjad) підтверджує прикладами), що безуфіксні іменники чоловічого роду другої відміни можуть мати і закінчення `-і`.
- **Вживання прийменника.** [Вікісловник](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4) і [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/rjad) наводить приклади лише з прийменником `в`. Як на мене, то перш за все варто звернути увагу на значення цього слова. *Ряд* - [це](http://sum.in.ua/s/rjad):

  > cукупність однорідних предметів або живих істот, розташованих одне
  >   поруч з одним, одне за одним, витягнутих в одну лінію.

В загальному випадку ми кажемо *в ряду*. Тому, думаю, сюди можна сміливо
   додати і ряди місць в (кіно)театрі.